# Error instantiating servlet class in the project which uses classes from the other project

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets

I have two project A and B. I connected A to B using JavaBuildPath.
Classes from A are utilized in B.
When I send first request I get the page "HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class".

Last messages from console:

> SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet [ServletName]
>
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: [class from A]
>
> > at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
> >
> > at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)

Answer (score 0):

Your build path is only known at compile time.
Check the runtime class path in your servlet engine.
E.g. Preferences -> Tomcat.